# Invalid argument supplied in register_taxonomy $args->taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have capabilities assigned in my `register_post_type()`. Then, I implemented taxonomies on my plugin. Where the $args in taxonomy are as follows:

```
$args = array(
  'label'=>'Partner Type',
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => __('Partners'),
    'singular_name' => __('Partner Type'),
    'menu_name' => __('Partner Types'),
    'all_items' => __('All Partner Types'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Partner Type'),
    'view_item' => __('View Partner Type'),
    'update_item' => __('Update Partner Type'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Partner Type'),
    'new_item_name' => __('NEw Item Type'),
    'parent_item' => __('Parent Type'),
    'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Partner Colon'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Partner'),
    'popular_items' => __('Popular Partner Type'),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate partner types with commas'),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __('Add or Remove Partner Types'),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __('Choose from Most Used Partner Type'),
    'not_found' => __('Partner Type Not Found'),
  ),
  'hierarchical' => true,
);
```

register_taxonomy('partner_taxonomies', 'partners',$args);

$args in `post_type` contains:

```
'taxonomies' => 'partner_taxonomies',
```

Then, I get the error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /var/www/html/stecLive/wp-includes/post.php on line 1346

Where the code says:

```
foreach ( $args->taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy, $post_type );
}
```

I don't see 'taxonomies' as one of the arguments in `register_taxonomy()`. How would you use or supply an array for 'taxonomies'? Or in other words, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it now...

The error inside 'taxonomies' belong to `register_post_type()` function. It does not belong to `register_taxonomy()`. The right way of declaring 'taxonomies' inside `register_post_type()` is:

```
'taxonomies' => array('partner_type_taxonomies'),
```